# P4V: What is the difference between merge down and merge any in perforce streams

Tags: perforce, p4merge, perforce-branch-spec, perforce-stream

What is the difference between `merge any` and `merge down` in Perforce P4V?.  when I try to create a stream in Perforce I am seeing these two options in **Advanced settings/options**.

Answer (score 0):

The "merge any" option allows a merge operation to be done in either direction (up or down), whereas the default "merge down" requires that you only merge down (and must copy up instead of merging up).

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt:

```
#963443 (Bug #65298, #74627) **
    The new 'mergeany' stream option allows flow rules for 'p4 merge'
    to be ignored for a particular stream.  The default option of
    'mergedown' preserves the previously existing flow rules.  Streams
    created by 'p4 switch' on a personal server use 'mergeany'.
```